# Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't load captive portal

Tags: wireless, laptop, 17.10, acer

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop, and there have been a host of problems with wifi. The one that I am trying to solve right now is the fact that it connects to a network, but it does not load the captive portal. When I open a browser to load the captive portal, it also fails. I have tried resetting network and NetworkManager, both of which fail after timing out.

My laptop is an Acer Aspire E 15 E5-575-33BM.

Answer (score 1):

Captive portals are weird.

You may just need to visit a non-HTTPS web page to actually trigger the captive page loading, as HTTPS pages can't normally be intercepted/redirected by the gateway.

One such well-known example of a non-HTTPS site is http://captive.apple.com, and is actually what Apple products use to check for a captive portal. Another well-known page is http://www.msftncsi.com/ which does (roughly) the same thing for Windows devices. There are many others on the web as well if you'd rather use those.

Try using one of these in your browser first, and it may cause the captive page to kick in and load.

Comment: When I try this, it redirects to the captive portal but the browser still says "Server not found"

Comment: Worked for me, xubuntu 18.10. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

As **root**, do the following:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

This immediately solved the problem for me. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Overwriting `resolv.conf` is discouraged in normal Network Manager configurations. It would be better to change the name server in NM. -1

Comment: You are correct it is discouraged. However this is a quick way to see whether the problem is actually fixed, and you can then decide if you want to make the solution permanent somehow else.

Why would you edit resolv.conf at all if the problem persists?